# Why do i see 2 different splash screens one after another?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, splash-screen

I'm using phonegap-build, last week i started seeing 2 diffrent splash screens one after another?

This is a bit of code in my config.xml related to this specific problem:

```
 <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <gap:splash src="Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

     <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-667h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <gap:splash src="Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
```

And i have this plugin that i use:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen"   source="npm" version="2.1.0" />
```

Testing on iphone 5, what is the cause of the two splashscreens appear one after another?

UPDATE:
If i remove the splashscreen plugin, i see a splash screen for 1 second, then white screen, and the i see my app.

i want to see the initial splash screen just until the app is ready (device ready)

Comment: but are both of them your images? or first you see the phonegap build robot and then your image?

Comment: Both my images, not the build robot

Comment: the thing is iOS uses a launch image (can't be avoided), and then, if you install the splash screen plugin, you show the same image again, but that shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: You are right, the problem is, it's the same image but for some reason it rotates or something, seems not full screen, what can be the cause of this?